Databricks Delta Live Tables Rename Streaming Table
I have a delta live talbes pipeline and need to change the name of a streaming table in the pipeline. Is there a best practive to achieve this in dlt?
I am looking for best practices as these tables are different than regular delta tables

can you share your approach you have tired so far?

What does your current pipeline look like? How many tables does it current process/populate? Have you considered changing the table name and refreshing the pipeline so that all the data is re-processed? If there is only 1 set of tables, this should be fine, but if you pipeline has 10s of 100s of tables this will not be a feasible solution.

According to the documentation CREATE STREAMING TABLE for Delta Live Tables,

Renaming a streaming table or changing its owner is not supported.

The following operations cannot be used with streaming tables:

Creating a table by cloning a streaming table
Using the COPY INTO command
Analyzing a table
Restoring a table
Truncating a table
Generating a manifest
Creating or replacing a table

Know more about Limitations
